# Getting one-to-many relationship data both ways in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework to create the following endpoints:

`/tenants/` ➞ lists all tenants and includes in the json response the attributes of the Building model they live in.

`/buildings/` ➞ lists all buildings and includes in the json response the attributes of the Tenants that live in them.

My models are:

```py
class Building(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Tenant(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name = 'tenants', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers look like so:

```py
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city']

class TenantSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    building = BuildingSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'building']
```

The `/tenants/` endpoint works just fine, but I have no idea on how to include the tenants' data in the `/buildings/` response.

Could anyone give me a clue on this?

Comment: since you have given building a related name, you can just use it as a normal field with the name of `tenant`, like `Building.tenants`

Comment: @MoPo adding 'tenants' to the serializer's fields return the following error: `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "tenant-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.`

Answer (score 0):

```py
#models.py:
class Building(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.address+self.city

class Tenant(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name = 'tenantsRN', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname+self.lname+" tenant"


#in serializers.py
#if you have not used related name u need to use _set
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tenantsRN=serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)# gets self.fname+self.lname+" tenant"
    tenantsRN = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
                many=True,
                read_only=True,
                slug_field='fname')
    class Meta:
        model=Building
        fields = ('id', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city','tenantsRN')
        #you can use string related field or slug related field based on requirement
        #or you can use HyperlinkedIdentityField for customize

# in views.py
class allview(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=BuildingSerializer()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Building.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the reverse association list we need to do the following.

1. Create a SerializerMethodField in BuildingSerializer as follows.

```
rom rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Tenant,Building
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tenants_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model=Building
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city','tenants_list']
    
    def get_tenants_list(self,obj):
        return list(obj.tenants.all().values_list('id',"fname","lname"))
```

In the above we first defined a custom method field named `tenants_list`, the value for this list will be the return value of the method get_tenants_list

In the get tenants_list method, we will receive a self-object and an obj parameter pointing to the current building object in response.

Here is a screenshot of the output after I have tested the solution.

[image]

We are calling the tenants method on the current obj to get the list of tenants associated with the building and use the `values_list` method to convert the QuerySet to a list to avoid serializing issues.

As a final step add the tenants_list field to the fields list in the Meta class.